# restfullyii Defining Custom Routes

Tags: api

i bulit api using yii restful extension  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/

i want create api  for login which accept username and password then  return all user

information i think the correct way to do that is to create custom router after checking

extension documentation section Defining Custom Routes  the author say i must create http verb combination (event name = 'req..\.render')

[POST] api/login/login

to create url i do this

```
main.php

 array('<controller>/req.post.login', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),


login Controller :
public function restEvents()
    {
        $this->onRest('req.post.login.render', function() {
            echo "sss";
            //Custom logic for this route.
            //Should output results.
            $this->emitRest('req.render.json', [
                    [
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'data'=>['active'=>true]
                    ]
                    ])
        });
    }

  restEvents  didn't fire any help ??
```

Answer (score 1):

**to create custom routing add this to  controler and url will be http://css.local.com/index.php/api/controlername/test**

```
    $this->onRest('req.post.test.render',function() {


        $this->emitRest('req.render.json', [
                [
                'type'=>'raw',
                'data'=>data
                ]
                ]);
    });
```